# How to set progress bar in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, progress

I am trying to set the progress bar. I have  a list contain 1000 numbers but progressbar showing up to 100.

```
a=range(1000)
for i in a:
    arcpy.SetProgressor("step", "Copying shapefiles to geodatabase...",0, len(a), 1)
    arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()
```

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap to do this?  Is this being used with a Python Script tool?  If so, does it have any parameters?

Comment: I've only used ArcMap, but I always updated the message to specify the exact count while the bar filled to 100 percent.

Comment: i am useing arcmap

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't appear that the ArcPy progress bar permits arbitrary values in `step` mode.  The [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/setprogressor.htm) does state (emphasis mine):

> step — The progressor shows the **percentage complete**.

Your code isn't complete, since the operation needs to happen inside a Python toolbox to see the result, but if I create a nominal Python toolbox and add your code to the `execute()` function, but place the `SetProgressor` *outside* the loop, and add a sub-second delay with `time.sleep()` to make the operation take long enough to be visible, like this:

```
    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        import time

        a = range(1000)
        arcpy.SetProgressor("step", "Copying shapefiles to geodatabase...",0, len(a), 1)
        for i in a:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()

        return
```

I get the expected 0-100% completion bar:

[image: nominal percent progress]

If I add a label to format the individual progress, then I get closer to what you seem to want...

```
    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        import time

        a = range(1000)
        arcpy.SetProgressor("step", "Copying shapefiles to geodatabase...",0, len(a), 1)
        for i in a:
            arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Copying shapefile {:4d} of {:d} to geodatabase...".format(i+1,len(a)))
            time.sleep(0.01)
            arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()

        return
```

[image]